# Change dynamically class in ionic with angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-formly

i have the next code, i want change the **class** when the value is equal to "abc" but i can't add some class :

```
  $scope.formFields = [
    {
      key: 'email',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type:'email',
        placeholder: 'Correo',
        required:true,
        class: 'some-clase'
      }
    }]
```

now, I know well then the change is done but I can not even add a simple class :

```
  expressionProperties: {
        'templateOptions.class': '"glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-"'
        }
```

help me please , if they can add an example in jsbin, codepen... thanks

Comment: Change the class of what?

Comment: @Fals  the className in  tag created in the hrml

Comment: Did you tried ng-class at the element?

Comment: @Fals  is true but how can make this in  json of angular-formly ?

Comment: You should consider to render a default class using formly and use ng-class in the view to change It.

Comment: Exactly , but the configuration un the html limit this , because ng-formly use the directive with the json params ex: <formly-form model="model" fields="formFields"

Comment: Did you tried ng-class? Probably will work

Comment: @Fals, angular-formly is an abstraction on top of forms in angular that gives you a lot of benefits from a reusability standpoint. While you can accomplish this using an `ng-class` in the template with angular-formly, the template this configuration is using is pre-defined and there's actually a better way to do this. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

Your `expressionProperties` property is a [formly expression](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.14.0/docs/formly-expressions) and can therefore be a function. It should probably be something more like this:

```
'templateOptions.class': function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
  if ($viewValue === 'abc') {
    return 'some-class';
  } else {
    return 'some-other-class';
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note - if you want to dynamically modify the className (not a custom class), you should replace 'templateOptions.class' with 'className'.